# Computation Complexity books for a mathematician

Tags: complexity-theory, books

I recently attented to some computational complexity talks (or complexity theory, I am not sure which is the correct name) and I fell in love with it. I would like to find some books, online courses... in general resources of any kind to self-study this (securely) wonderfull subject.

My backgrund is pure mathematics with emphasys in discrete mathematics (graph theorey, crypto, coding thoery, combinatorics...), with no background in computer science. I am not sure if the last one is mandatory.

Comment: Seeing the other answers now, I feel like this question is best answered with a community wiki answer. If @Discretelizard and Mars agree that I incorporate their recommendations into my answer, I'll make it a wiki and update.

Comment: @PålGD For me that would be perfect! I will check them all and see what I like most!

Comment: Shouldn't this question be on the [CS Theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: @einpoklum no, cstheory is for computer scientists and researchers in related fields.  This is not a research related question.  But I do admit that we have very overlapping interests.

Comment: I don't know about the community wiki, @PålGD, but that is fine with me.

Comment: About whether you need a CS background, Bean Guy, I think of computational complexity and computability as math that happens to be taught in CS departments.  At one point I asked a computability question on math.SE and I was told to come over here.  I didn't know. Of course there are applications of this math, too--but not only to computers.

Comment: @Mars That is why I liked the talks on cc that much: the methodology in this subject seems to be like those in math (so definitions, result, proofs, definition, results, proofs...).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Michael Sipser's text book [Introduction to the Theory of
Computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_the_Theory_of_Computation)
is a classic introduction to computation theory, and gives an
introduction to complexity theory in the end.

I don't know how to answer the question better than just providing the
table of contents of the book.

```
PART 1: AUTOMATA AND LANGUAGES.
1. Regular Languages.
2. Context-Free Languages.

PART 2: COMPUTABILITY THEORY.
3. The Church-Turing Thesis.
4. Decidability.
5. Reducibility.
6. Advanced Topics in Computability Theory.

PART 3: COMPLEXITY THEORY.
7. Time Complexity.
8. Space Complexity.
9. Intractability.
10. Advanced Topics in Complexity Theory.
```

Comment: I suppose that the difference between Computability and Complexity is that, in the first one cares about if a problem is computable or not, and in the second one, one cares about the efficiency of such a computable problems. Am I right, more or less?

Comment: I would say that computability deals with the fundamental properties of (mainly) Turing machines and other automata. Complexity theory typically deals with more fine-grained analysis of machines. Be aware that you need to know some computation theory in order to understand complexity theory.

Comment: +1; Sipser was my first thought on seeing the HNQ title. (It's one of the very few textbooks I found I was able to learn from just by reading the book and following the exercises.)

Comment: @BeanGuy Yes you are right, more or less.

Answer (score 8):

You might want to consider [Computational Complexity: A Modern Approach](http://www.cambridge.org/us/catalogue/catalogue.asp?isbn=9780521424264) by Arora and Barak.  Roughly speaking, its early chapters overlap with later chapters in Sipser, and it has more material on computational complexity per se.

Arora and Barak's book (A&B) seems self-contained.  For example, you don't need to know the parts of Sipser or similar books that A&B don't cover, in order to understand A&B.  On the other hand, my sense is that A&B moves a little bit more quickly and requires a little bit more insight than Sipser.  I could be wrong.  I am reading A&B and have only glanced at parts of Sipser and have read a few comments online comparing the two.

In terms of content, my guess is that A&B is one good option for your interests, and if the level of A&B is inappropriate for you, it will be because it is too easy (it's not, for me), and because some other book goes into ideas more deeply more quickly.

Comment: It's self-contained because it's a million pages long...

Comment: I suppose that true self-containment would require a much longer book, with at least a countably infinite number of pages.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the book [*Computational Complexity Theory*](https://bookstore.ams.org/pcms-10),
edited by Steven Rudich and Avi Wigderson, which is based on a graduate summer school by the IAS/Park city mathematics institute, with lectures by various experts in the field.

The purpose of this book is to provide the basics, some history and a glimpse into the research in some areas of computational complexity theory, aimed at mathematics students.

As such, this book is not a replacement for an introductory book such as Sisper's, but can be read independently to get a feeling what some sub-fields of complexity theory look like, and can help to guide a future focus.

For completeness, I'll list a summary of the table of contents as well (see this [Google books preview](https://books.google.nl/books?id=cL8jDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ViewAPI&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) for the full table):

```
Week One:
COMPLEXITY THEORY: FROM GÖDEL TO FEYNMAN

Steven Rudich, Complexity Theory: from Gödel to Feynmann    
Avi Wigderson, Average case Complexity
Sanjeev Arora, Exploring Complexity through Reductions 
Ran Raz, Quantum Computation

Week Two: 
LOWER BOUNDS

Ran Raz, Circuit and Communication Complexity
Paul Beame, Proof Complexity

Week Three:
RANDOMNESS IN COMPUTATION

Oded Goldreich, Pseudorandomness - Part I
Luca Trevisan, Pseudorandomness - Part II
Sadil Vadhan, Probabilistic Proof Systems - Part I
Madhu Sudan, Probablistically Checkable Proofs
```

Comment: That is not an introductory text, nor a comprehensive reference, but rather a collection of advanced topics.

Comment: @einpoklum I don't claim that this text is either, nor a replacement for them. It is suitable for self study for (somewhat advanced) mathematics students, which was what the question asked.

Comment: The thing is, it is suitable, I belive, only for someone who already has a decent grasp of complexity theory.

Comment: @einpoklum Fair enough. I disagree, since I personally was able to read the book with barely any background in complexity theory, but this may be different for others.